# What does this complex tr command do?

Tags: linux, command-line

```
tr '\0' '\071' < /dev/zero | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M conv=fsync 2>/dev/null
```

This command is run immediately after a dd command which zeros out the disk. It changes the hexdump output from

```
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
7745d6000
```

to

```
0000000 3939 3939 3939 3939 3939 3939 3939 3939
*
7745d6000
```

But I can't figure out exactly what the command is intended to accomplish

Answer (score 5):

Let’s split this up:

```
tr '\0' '\071' < /dev/zero
```

reads from `/dev/zero`, which produces zero bytes, and replaces all zero bytes (`'\0'`) with bytes containing 71 in octal (`'\071'`), *i.e.* the digit 9 in ASCII, or 0x39 in hexadecimal (which is what `hexdump` shows). The result is a never-ending stream of 0x39 bytes.

```
dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M conv=fsync 2>/dev/null
```

takes this input (all 9s) and writes it to `/dev/sda`, 1 megabyte at a time, ensuring that data is written out before finishing.

`dd` stops when it reaches the end of `/dev/sda`; this causes `tr` to stop too (it can no longer write to the pipe and stops).

Presumably the purpose is to obscure any data previously present on the drive; whether this is actually useful is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't figure out exactly what the command is intended to accomplish

It replaces null bytes with 071 (0x39 57 00111001) bytes. No idea how it can be useful.

Normally if you want to check the drive health you use other patterns, e.g.

```
00000000 0000  0x0
11111111 0377 0xFF
01010101 0125 0x55
10101010 0252 0xAA
```

All these values are used by e.g. `badblocks`